# jenkins pipeline using gcloud is not working

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, gcloud

I'm trying to set up jenkins pipeline using gcloud but I'm getting the following error:

> gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file
>   ./service-account-creds.json WARNING: Could not setup log file in
>   /.config/gcloud/logs, (Error: Could not create directory
>   [/.config/gcloud/logs/2019.02.07]: Permission denied.

the code:

```
stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'google-container-registry', variable: 'GOOGLE_AUTH')]) {
                    script {
                        docker.image('google/cloud-sdk:latest').inside {
                            sh "echo ${GOOGLE_AUTH} > gcp-key.json"
                            sh 'gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file ./service-account-creds.json'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Jenkins is running in a container using the imagen jenkins/jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'google-container-registry', variable: 'GOOGLE_AUTH')]) {
    script {
        docker.image('google/cloud-sdk:latest').inside {
            sh "echo ${GOOGLE_AUTH} > gcp-key.json"
            sh "gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=${GOOGLE_AUTH}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working for me: ```+ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=****
WARNING: Could not setup log file in /.config/gcloud/logs, (Error: Could not create directory [/.config/gcloud/logs/2021.03.22]: Permission denied.```